# How to create an SEO friendly custom post type title using Yoast

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, php, title

I have used this code to filter `$title` of a custom post type, and it works perfectly fine when there are search results on the post type e.g A query for Mercedes Benz cars for sale in Paris would show a `$title` like this **Mercedes Benz used cars for sale in Paris on Sitename**

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'vehicle_listing_title');
function vehicle_listing_title( $title ) 
{
  if ( get_post_type() == 'vehicles' )
  {
    $location = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_location');
    $model = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_model');
    $title = $model[0]->name . 'used cars for sale in' . $location[0]->name .'on'. get_bloginfo('name');
  }
  return $title;
}
```

But then again, when there aren’t any search results on the post type, the code returns a single term title e.g A query for Mercedes Benz cars for sale in Paris would show a `$title` like this **Mercedes Benz archives – Sitename** I need this to return filtered `$title` for all search queries, because I have a sitemap pulling these Urls from the custom post type.

I need this to function for SEO reasons. I want to avoid duplication of titles, because it will affect rankings.

I’ve been struggling with this for some time now.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: While your intentions are SEO the solution you require is one that requires WordPress development which makes this question off-topic on Pro Webmasters. Normally we would migrate questions across but there is already a vast amount of questions regarding [Yoast title](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Yoast+TITLE) on that Stack. You should be able to repost this question on the WordPress Dev Stack but do check existing questions and answers before reposting to avoid further disappointment.